# Resource blocked due to MIME-type conflict ("application/json") (X-Content-type-options: nosniff)

Tags: html, css, footer

I just designed a footer for a web application my team and I are implementing. When I load the html files and access them, the footer looks fine.
However, when one of my teammates do the same the footer has no style attributes at all and is appearing on the right side of the page.

It is fairly hard to debug since it works on my end, but I got sent the error message in the title.

Here's my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.83.1">

    <title>Central SignIn</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sign-in/">

    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href=
                  "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity=
                  "sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I"
          crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src=
                    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity=
                    "sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src=
                    "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity=
                    "sha384-oesi62hOLfzrys4LxRF63OJCXdXDipiYWBnvTl9Y9/TRlw5xlKIEHpNyvvDShgf/"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="footerSmallPage.css" media="all">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sign-in/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="text-center">

<main class="form-signin">

    <form name="f">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Central Service Sign in</h1>

        <!-- Email input field -->
        <div class="form-floating">
            <input name= "username" type="email" class="form-control"
            id="floatingInput"
                   placeholder="name@example.com">
            <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
        </div>

        <!-- Password input field -->
        <div class="form-floating">
            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control"
                   id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
            <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
        </div>

        <!-- Login button -->
        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>

    </form>

    <form action="/home" method="get">
        <input type="submit" name="Go to the overview" id="overviewButton" />
    </form>
        <!-- Button for Navigation - Opens modal on click -->
            <button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-dark al"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#navigation">
                Navigation
            </button>

    <!-- Modal initialization -->
    <div class="modal fade"
         id="navigation">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h2 class="modal-title">
                        Navigation</h2>
                    <button type="button"
                            class="close"
                            data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">
                              X</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!--Modal Text-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p style="font-size:20px"> Copyright © 2021 </p>
                    <p> Gruppe20 Web & Data Engineering </p>
                    <p> All rights reserved. </p>
                    <br>
                    <p style="font-size:20px;"> <h3> Authors: </h3> </p>
                    <p> Emily Vorderwuelbeke </p>
                    <p> Severin Burghart </p>
                    <p> Ludwig Loggenkamp </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</main>
<footer class="footer">
    <br>
    <br>
    <p> Copyright © 2021 - Gruppe20 Web & Data Engineering - All rights reserved </p>
    <p> Authors: Emily Vorderwuelbeke - Severin Burghart - Ludwig Roggenkamp</p>
</footer>
</body>
<script>
    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(event.target);
        const value = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());

        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(value)
        };
        console.log(value);
        console.log(options)
        fetch( 'login', options )
            .then( response => document.cookie =
                "Authorization="+response.headers.get("Authorization")+";path=/;expiration=0;");

    }
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);

</script>
</html>
```

and here is the css file (it is in the same folder as the html pages)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .footer{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
    }
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: black;
    height: 177px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(footer-image.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified the wrong file path here.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="footerSmallPage.css" media="all">
```

It will actually go like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./footerSmallPage.css" media="all">
```

Comment: You are probably showing the wrong file path. Can you show the folder build?

Comment: So you mean your teammate is getting the error during the page load? I copied your code as it is but could not replicate the issue, the CSS is getting loaded as usual.

Comment: @ercüment I changed it now so the css is inside the html file. the styling now works, and when displaying the file in chrome through the IntelliJ button it works with background aswell. However when I start the server the styling is correct, but the background image is missing.

Comment: @sas correct. Now I get the error too that the background image is not loading when accessing the server through url and not just displaying the html file through IntelliJ chrome shortcut